# Searching for probability of difference of standard normal variable and maximum of observations from iid standard normal variables.

Tags: probability, statistics, order-statistics

$X_1, \dots, X_7$ and $Y_1, \dots, Y_8$ are $\text{iid}$ with $N(\mu, \sigma)$ distribution.

---

I want to calculate a probability: $P(X_1<Y_{(8)})$, where $Y_{(8)}$ is $\max(Y_1, \dots, Y_8)$. I don' t know if I should search for a distribution of $X_1-Y_{(8)}$ and if so, I do not know how.

I will be grateful for any help in this task.

Answer (score 2):

I'll do this by finding the probability of the complementary event $\big[ X_1\ge Y_{(8)} \big].$ Then you can subtract that from $1.$

First **the hard way:**
$$
\require{cancel}
\xcancel{
\begin{align}
& \text{The answer is the same regardless of the values} \\
& \text{of $\mu$ and $\sigma^2,$ so I will do this using $\mu=0,$ $\sigma^2=1.$} \\[8pt]
& \Pr(X_1 \ge Y_{(8)}) \\[8pt] = {} & \operatorname E( \Pr(X_1\ge Y_{(8)} \mid X_1)) \\[8pt]
= {} & \operatorname E(\Pr(\text{all of } Y_1,\ldots,Y_8 \text{ are} \le X_1\mid X_1)) \\[8pt]
= {} & \operatorname E((\Phi(X_1))^8) \\[8pt]
= {} & \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} (\Phi(x))^8 \varphi(x)\,du \\[8pt]
= {} & \int_0^1 u^8\, du = \frac 1 9. \\ \phantom{+}
\end{align}
}
$$
All correct, but here's the easy way:
$$
\Pr\left( \begin{array}{l} \text{among nine iid random} \\
\text{variables } X_1,Y_1\ldots,Y_8, \\
\text{the largest is } X_1 \end{array} \right) = \frac 1 9
$$
by symmetry.

Comment: Thank You for Your answer. Okay, I get this second way of solving my problem, but regarding to the first idea, where does the transition $\Pr(X_1\ge Y_{(8)})=E( \Pr(X_1\ge Y_{(8)} \mid X_1))$ come from?

Comment: @hermione : That is the law of total probability: $\Pr(A) = \operatorname E(\Pr(A\mid U)),$ for any random variable $U.$ If (lower-case) $u$ is any particular value that the random variable (capital) $U$ can take, then $\Pr(A\mid U=u)$ is merely a conditional probability given an event. It clearly depends on the value of (lower-case) $u,$ so it is a function of (lower-case) $u,$ which we may denote $g(u)$ (with a lower-case $u$). So $g(U)$ (with a capital $U$) is a random variable. The law of total probability says that its expected value is $\Pr(A). \qquad$

Comment: Very late, but thank You for the response!